# Identity Server 4 Identity related scope requests, but no openid scope

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, scope, resources, identityserver4

I'm trying to add a custom resource/scope and for my testing I chose it to be email but as I understand it can be any value. So for my resources I have this:

```
return new List<IdentityResource>
{
    new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
    new IdentityResources.Profile(),
    new IdentityResource("email", "Email", new [] { "email" })
    //new IdentityResources.Email()  -- This was tried as well, same error.
};

return new List<ApiResource> { new ApiResource("test", "Test") };
```

Then for scopes on the client its as follows:

```
AllowedScopes = new List<string>
{
    "openid", "profile", "email", "test"
}
```

However, when I request a token with `http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize?Scope=test email` the page errors out and in my lows I see

> 2019-07-05 11:08:00.681 -04:00 [ERR] Invalid scope: email
>   2019-07-05 11:08:00.684 -04:00 [ERR] Request validation failed

I'm really not sure where I went wrong. According to all docs and SO posts I found, this is how its done.

EDIT: There was an internal bug which was overlooked and was causing wrong `List<IdentityResource>` to be passed. However, even after resolving this it still cause a problem with a different error message now:

> Identity related scope requests, but no openid scope

Edit 2:

After some help form d_f, I have realized that I needed to update my request which now looks like this:

> /connect/authorize?scope=test openid email&response_type=id_token token&nonce=NONCE

I now get authorized and I can see the email scope in the claims. However, even though I see email as a scope, I don't see the actual email anywhere in the claims.

Comment: your request missed the `openid` scope. the only always required by the protocol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see the answer requires some theoretical background.
As you can find in any fundamental work or the original [specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html), OpenID Connect protocol became a combination of OpenId and OAuth. OIdC is compatible with the second one, as you could see during your request transformation. What is new for OIdC is additional *identity token*. OAuth introduces *access* aka *bearer* token + *refresh token* to get a fresh *access* one when the existing expires. All this stuff is about access to API using bearer authorization http header. And the new *identity token* represents a user session for the application, not an api.

The payload for `identity_token` and `access_token` in Identity server 4 is controlled by two separate dictionaries [`IdentityResources`](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/identity_resource.html) and [`ApiResources`](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/api_resource.html) correspondingly. Unfortunately you can not add a scope into both at the same time. But you can define two different scopes with the same claim. For instance:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
{
    return new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource
        {
            Name = "test-api",
            Scopes =
            {
                new Scope
                {
                    Name = "test",
                    UserClaims =
                    {
                        JwtClaimTypes.SessionId,
                        JwtClaimTypes.Role,
                        Constants.TenantIdClaimType,
                        JwtClaimTypes.Email,
                        JwtClaimTypes.Locale
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

public static List<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
{
    // Claims automatically included in OpenId scope
    var openIdScope = new IdentityResources.OpenId();
    openIdScope.UserClaims.Add(JwtClaimTypes.Locale);

    // Available scopes
    return new List<IdentityResource>
    {
        openIdScope,
        new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        new IdentityResources.Email(),
        new IdentityResource(Constants.RolesScopeType, Constants.RolesScopeType,
                    new List<string> {JwtClaimTypes.Role, Constants.TenantIdClaimType})
            {
                Required = true
            }
    };
}
```

In this example we added possibility to get email claim in `access_token` as a part of the `test` scope and in `id_token` as a part of the standard `email` scope.

In addition we have to keep in mind that the `id_token` is optimized for size by default  and has only the protocol-required claims in it's payload. All the additional claims could be requested additionally from [`Userinfo` endpoint](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/userinfo.html) of IdP. To get all the user claims within the `id_token`, you can set `AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken=true` in the client configuration in IdSrv.

Comment: What if the identity resources are not in-mem but stored in the DB and I get this weird message: *Scope openid not found in store or not supported by requested resource indicators*? It's connected to the client but for some reason still won't come up when I invoke */connect/authorize*...

Comment: the message means that [this search](https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer/blob/06ff163e53edb93f7a1f12ab2efc42c0c1272ace/src/IdentityServer/Validation/Default/DefaultResourceValidator.cs#L143) returns null. why? -- that must be up to the store implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In fact, I accidentally put `Enabled` to 0 for **all** scopes. (Probably, i forgot `where` in my SQL call.   :)

Answer (score 0):

Email is a standard identity resource.

Try

```
return new List<IdentityResource>
{
  new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
  new IdentityResources.Profile(),
  new IdentityResources.Email()
};
```

See [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html#defining-identity-resources)

If you want to add custom one, you can find it [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html#defining-custom-identity-resources)

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, I can switch it to any name and I get the same issue.

Comment: Client id is missing from auth request. Is it missing in your code too, or you just removed it to keep the question clean?

Comment: I updated my question, I resolved why that specific error was happening, but a different one has taken its place instead now. Also what do you mean by auth request? Which function are you saying the id is missing from and I'll check?

Comment: Your authorize request should contain client_id 
http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize?client_id={yourClientId}&scope=test email

but now I see your updated question, and I think it will be something else.
I've never seen this error before, have to check.

Comment: Yes the clientId is being passed. Actually everything works fine if I don't try to request the scope email. if I only request test then it passes fine and I can use my apis with that token.

Comment: @Bojan when you don't request the openid scope, the protocol downgrades to oauth. that's ok unless you request any identity scopes -- an extension added by openid connect

Comment: @d_f so you are saying as part of my request I have to include openid in scopes? I tried that already but I still got same error. Am I missing something?

Comment: @d_f Actually I lied, sorry, the error is this if I add openid as one of the scopes in my request `Requests for token response type only must include resource scopes, but no identity scopes.`

Comment: @Bojan good then. your request for `identity` must contain `&response_type=id_token%20token` (in case of implicit flow)

Comment: @d_f it seems the errors are just piling up. Here is what I tried: `/connect/authorize?scope=test openid email&response_type=id_token token` and the error that I get is `Nonce required for implicit and hybrid flow with openid scope`

Comment: the time was close to the weekend, I had to leave : )  but finally I added a bit about nonce... https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196055/discussion-between-bojan-and-d-f

Answer (score 0):

You add the `IdentityResources.Email()`claim in `IdentityResource` , that means `id_token` will include the user's email information . You can decode the `id_token` (not access token) using online tool like https://jwt.io/ to check the claims returned .

You can also set `AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken` to `true` in client config to see whether it includes the email claim :

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "mvc",
    ClientName = "MVC Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

    ....

    ....
    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        "api1",
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
    },
    AllowOfflineAccess = true
},
```

In addition , there are different kinds(authentication flows) of IdentityServer 4 Quickstart Samples :

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts

You can start to customize the client/IDS4 based on the code samples .